# UIImageView inside UITableViewCell is laid out incorrectly in edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a fairly simple `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

Nothing extraordinary, but I ran into an issue. Whenever I enable the edit mode, the position and size of `UIImageView` change, *completely ignoring the constraints that pin it to the edges of its superview* (the one with blue background):

[image]

The superview is laid out correctly:

[image]

I expected to see messages about broken constraints in the system log, but there is nothing of the sort.

**Why does this happen and how do I fix it?**

Here's a project that reproduces the issue: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0NvLeUettZub5uQIXUM4p0bGw#TestApp

---

**EDIT:** I tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the image container when the edit mode is activated:

```
class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        noteImageView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

now the layout is incorrect even if I don't enable the edit mode.

**EDIT 2:** @Desdenova suggested that this might be caused by the horizontal `UIStackView`, but replacing it with equivalent constraints did not fix the problem.

Comment: Nicely asked question. Nice and clear :) Looking at project now. Did you try: setNeedsLayout on the view?

Comment: @Woodstock thank you :) Which view do you mean? The image container?

Comment: I would have thought the UITableViewCell’s View

Comment: Also try calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() where self is the tableviewCell. (After invoking the edit of course)

Comment: @Woodstock Obviously edit mode lays out the sub views. My best guess would be horizontal stack view is misbehaving. And I don't think he even needs that stack view.

Comment: @Woodstock I tried what you suggested, see the edit.

Comment: @Desdenova if this issue were caused by the horizontal stack, the image container layout would be affected too, but it is not. Anyway, I tried replacing the horizontal stack with equivalent constraints, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it ?

Comment: @OthmanT no, I wasn't able to find any solution or workaround.

Comment: I did just fix my problem by noticing that I was using the same name (imageView) for my image view, I renamed it and there is no more problem.